# Stop all threads in a custom thread pool (like shutting down)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

In Java library thread pool implementations, usually shutting down a pool means:

-stop accepting new tasks

-previously submitted tasks are executed

**-all pool threads are terminated**

Regarding the last point, how would you stop a pool thread that could potentially try to take a new task, *after* it has been stopped?

My threads do something like this (in java pseudo code):

```
public void run() {
  while(!isStopped) {
    Task task = taskQueue.take(); //line1
    task.run(); //line2
  }
}
```

and have a method stop:

```
public synchronized void stop(){
  isStopped = true;
  this.interrupt();
}
```

In my thread pool class, I have a method stop:

```
public synchronized void shutdown(){
  this.isShutdown = true; //to stop the whole pool
  for(PoolThread thread : threads)
    thread.stop();
}
```

**The point is, if a thread reaches line 1, isStopped was false, but at that same moment it could be set to true by the pool class. How do I remember that I should stop the thread again? Does calling interrupt suffice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the shutdown messages through the task queue:

```
static Task stop = // some special value

public void run() {
  while (true) {
    Task task = taskQueue.take();
    if (task == stop) {
        break;
    }
    task.run();
  }
}
```

and in `shutDown`:

```
public synchronized void shutdown(){
  if (isShutdown) {
    return;
  }
  this.isShutdown = true;
  for(PoolThread thread : threads) {
    taskQueue.put(PoolThread.stop);
  }
}
```

With a number of shutdown messages in the queue equal to the number of threads, once all work is completed, the threads will each take a shutdown message and shut down. (Note that we don't need to care about which thread gets which shutdown message.)

Comment: Thanks. I liked this solution. What about the shutdownNow? It is like shutdown, but only the threads already executing a task can terminate their work. No new task can be added to the queue. Maybe, it is enough to empty the queue (with synchronized) and reuse this same idea? I think it could work. What do you say? Of course, if a thread is taking too long to complete a task this will block the whole shutdown (but if I am not mistaken, this is also true for the java library thread pools).

Comment: If a thread that gets a shutdown message requeues it before terminating itself, only one shutdown message is required for any number of pool threads.

Comment: @Kami: For `shutdownNow`, you'd want to drain the queue and interrupt the threads as well as sending shutdown messages.

Comment: @Martin James: good point, but how woul you signal that it was the *last* thread to quit? There is a third useful method in the java library: awaitTermination(...) that checks if all threads have terminated after a given timeout. If we use one shutdown message per thread (like user2357112  suggested), it could be implemented by simply checking if the queue still contains *at least* one shutdown message after the timeout, but if you alway reinsert the shutdown message, we lose that information.

Comment: Well, it kinda depends on whether you actually need to know when the last thread has terminated.  The pool is destroying itself on its own - do you need to know when it's all done?  Can you not just leave it alone to get on with its own suicide?

Comment: @Martin James: I have been playing around a bit with both solutions. In your solution the 'stop task' is a bit like a token that is passed around threads. When someone has the token the queue must have become empty (since after a shutdown we stop new insertions), so other threads must wait on taskQueue.take() a little. With multiple stop tasks, it could be done concurrently. I think that both solutions are ok, though.

Comment: @user2357112: I would like to make you a question about your solution. What if threads executing tasks are stopped with an interrupt exception when executing their tasks? Would not in that scenario remain 'dirty stop tasks'? It is probably ok, because your solution assures that there are enough stop tasks to stop all threads, but they could be more. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: @Kami: I'm not sure what you mean by dirty stop tasks. Do you mean stop tasks that don't get taken by a worker thread? There might be, depending on how your workers respond to the interrupt.